# SQL 2008 R2 : Could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, procedure

I am studying the SQL procedure.
I created a procedure and I execute. I was fine... and.  it displayed

> Could not find stored procedure when executed "exec my_procedure"

I am not really sure the reasons I am getting this error.  Did I choose the wrong directory to store the procedure?

Comment: What database & schema did you create it in?

Comment: Please show the code where you created the procedure and executed it.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably not in the right database within the query window. There should be a dropdown that shows the current database (possibly master). Choose the database you created the stored procedure in and then try again.

Comment: +1 because I don't know anyone to whom this has not happened at least once.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
USE my_database;
EXEC my_procedure;
```

Answer (score 3):

It tough to tell this could happen for several reasons.

1. you didn't actually execute the `create proc` when you thought you were
2. you accidentally executed `drop proc`
3. You're not connected to the right DB when you called `exec my_procedure`
4. You're using a different log on and it doesn't have access to the procedure
5. Its in a different schema than your default schema

You could run this to see if you proc is there at all in a given DB (or drop the where to see them all)

```
   select * 
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   where ROUTINE_NAME = 'my_procedure'
```

That said saving the Procedure Creation Script has no impact on your ability to execute it

Answer (score 0):

You can find all stored procedures by using the following command

```
exec my_database.my_schema.my_procedure
```

if still fail, can you provide us sp create a script?